# UITableViewCell height increases by 2 pixels on every rotation change

Tags: ios, ios4, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView outlet that I am populating with cells (set up as ivar outlets) that are defined in the same nib file as the table view controller. As I use the rotation feature, the first cell grows by 2 pixels every time that I rotate to a new orientation.

Here is the output from the console. I put a METHOD_LOG call in every method of the class so that I could see if the code was going somewhere unexpected, but it does not seem to be...

```
2011-06-08 10:10:42.050 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: viewDidLoad /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.054 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: viewWillAppear: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.054 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.056 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: numberOfSectionsInTableView: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.056 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.056 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.057 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.057 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.058 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.058 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.059 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.059 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.060 MyApp[10927:207] item name cell height: 44.000000
2011-06-08 10:10:42.060 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.060 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.061 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.061 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.062 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.062 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.062 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.063 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.063 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.064 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.064 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.065 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.065 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.065 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.066 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.066 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.067 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.067 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.068 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.068 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.068 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.069 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.069 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.070 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.070 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.071 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.071 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.071 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.072 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.072 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.073 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.073 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.074 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.074 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.074 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.075 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.075 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.076 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.076 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.077 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.077 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.077 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.078 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.078 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.079 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.079 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.080 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.080 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.080 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.081 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.081 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.082 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.082 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.082 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.083 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.083 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.084 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.085 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.086 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.087 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.088 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:42.088 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.619 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.622 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: numberOfSectionsInTableView: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.623 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.623 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.624 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.624 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.625 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.625 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:titleForHeaderInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.625 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.626 MyApp[10927:207] METHOD_LOG: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: /Users/me/path/to/the/source/code/ItemDetailViewController.m
2011-06-08 10:10:49.626 MyApp[10927:207] item name cell height: 46.000000
```

As you can see, after the view loads up, the only methods being called are shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and the table view delegate methods. The first time you see the cell height it is the default value as defined in Interface Builder, but the second time, it is somehow two pixels bigger. There is no code in any of those methods that is modifying the bounds or frame of any object whatsoever.

Anyone have any ideas of what could be going on or how to diagnose the issue? I thought about setting up a KVO, but I don't think I can get to the frame of the cell with that.

EDIT: Here is the code that returns the height for a row at a particular index path:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    METHOD_LOG;

    int idx = [indexPath section];

    if (idx == SECTION_ITEM)
    {
        NSLog(@"item name cell height: %f", itemNameCell.frame.size.height);
        return itemNameCell.frame.size.height;
    }
    else if (idx == SECTION_DESCRIPTION)
    {
        return itemDescriptionCell.frame.size.height;
    }
    ...
    ... other section identifiers here, you get the idea
    ...

    return 44.0;
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is the code that creates and returns the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    METHOD_LOG;

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    int idx = [indexPath section];

    if (idx == SECTION_ITEM)
    {
        cell = itemNameCell;
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        label.text = [[jobItem jItemRef] blankIfNULL];
    }
    else if (idx == SECTION_DESCRIPTION)
    {
        cell = itemDescriptionCell;
        UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        textView.text = [[jobItem jItemDesc] blankIfNULL];
    }
    ...
    ... again, you get the idea
    ...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How is your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the `itemNameCell`'s height to a static `CGFloat` in your method the first time it's needed, and then just use that from then on. I'd guess it's just some autoresizing in the UI that is stacking up as you rotate.

This assumes you won't *want* to change the height of the cell programmatically (since you're setting it up in IB).

Comment: Yeah, I know I could do that, I was hoping to get to the root of the problem. I am seeing this same problem on another view controller in the same app that is very similar.

Comment: I just hard coded the height values for now, as I have to move on to other issues. If anyone has any ideas in the near future, please post and I will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting this. It seems when the UITableView is grouped the cell view is resized by 2 pixels. It doesn't occur with plain style UITableView cells.

Since hardcoding the height (as suggested by Ben) was inconvenient (though it works), my solution was to implement my own UITableViewCell subclass and implement a rowHeight property and set this in awakeFromNib.

MyTableViewCell.h

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    CGFloat rowHeight;
}

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat rowHeight;

@end
```

MyTableViewCell.m

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell

@synthesize rowHeight;

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    self.rowHeight = self.frame.size.height;
}

@end
```

Then in your TableView delegate,

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
return itemDescriptionCell.rowHeight;
...
}
```

Caution: I've not tested this implementation in plain tableview or non-nib loaded scenarios.